# Cannot connect to SQL Azure

Tags: networking, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to connect to sql azure db from my work network.  My work network allows me to connect to sql server on my home machine :1443.  But for sql azure connection I have this.

```
===================================

Cannot connect to vx9jyb8***.database.windows.net.

===================================

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Error Number: 53
Severity: 20
State: 0


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()
```

my IP added to Allowed IP Addresses in Azure portal. I also create rule 1.1.1.1-255.255.255.255

ping is:

```
C:\Users\UName>ping vx9jyb8***.database.windows.net

Pinging data.bl2-1.database.windows.net [168.62.47.---] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 168.62.47.---: bytes=32 time=61ms TTL=108
Reply from 168.62.47.---: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=108
Reply from 168.62.47.---: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=108
Reply from 168.62.47.---: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=108

Ping statistics for 168.62.47.---:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 49ms, Maximum = 61ms, Average = 52ms
```

what can I do?

Comment: you might want to post your connection string so people can have a look if theres something wrong with it.

Comment: I use sql manager.
server: vx9jyb8---.database.windows.net
login: p---r
password: 1---(---3e

I think the problem in network only because everything is working from my home.  I can connect from work to my home sql server but not to azure....

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's a very simple thing, but not sure if you have tried. Create the portal Azure a rule to release your IP or your network.

If the problem still continues to report more data we can help you.

Regards,
Marcondes Alexandre